# awk - regex assigned to variable - broken

Tags: regex, variables, awk

Simple question to which I do not have the answer.

In a *.awk* script:

```
if ("test" ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/){
    print "MATCH"
} else {
    print "NOT MATCH"
}
```

will print MATCH

```
myvar = /^[[:alpha:]]+$/
if ("test" ~ myvar){
    print "MATCH"
} else {
    print "NOT MATCH"
}
```

will print NOT MATCH

I don't understand why. Is there an operator to get the value of myvar ? Is myvar just empty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) says

> When an ERE token appears as an expression in any context other than as the right-hand of the '~' or "!~" operator or as one of the built-in function arguments described below, the value of the resulting expression shall be the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> $0 ~ /ere/
> ```

That means;

```
myvar = /^[[:alpha:]]+$/
```

is the same as

```
myvar = ($0 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
```

You should wrap the ERE in double-quotes instead. Like

```
myvar = "^[[:alpha:]]+$"
```